# Display bar chart values from database with symfony 4

Tags: javascript, symfony, charts, twig

I'm trying to display values from my database using symfony 4, twig and javascript in bar chart graphic this is how my bar chart should look like

[image]

but this is what 've got

[image]

this is my code

```
<script>
{% for stock in stocks %}
var barChartData = {
    labels : ["{{ stock.idproduit.nom }}"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "#FC8213",
            data : [{{ stock.quantite }}]
}
]

};

new Chart(document.getElementById("bar").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData);
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What chart-library are you using? Is it chart.js? Are you sure, you want to create `barChartData` in a loop? This will overwrite the entry each time and only the last dataset is created.

Comment: yes that's what happened and I fixed it the for statement was not in the right place